# peer chaincode deploy -n mycc -c '{"Args": ["init", "a","100", "b", "200"]}' =>Error connecting to 0.0.0.0:7050 due to grpc: timed out when dialing

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm doing a project on hyperledger fabric and wish to run the chaincode.
but whenever i run this command

```
"peer chaincode deploy -n mycc -c '{"Args": ["init", "a","100", "b", "200"]}'"
```

in my GitBash,

It displayed an error i can't resolve.

```
"Error: Error getting broadcast client: Error connecting to 0.0.0.0:7050 due to grpc: timed out when dialing"
```

Is it a port issue?

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you list the steps please? By the look of it your peer is not started yet. Kindly check the peer status.

Answer (score 0):

7050 is the port of orderer service try to verify if you have it using docker images fabric-orderer if not use

```
 docker pull ${DOCKER_NS}/fabric-orderer:${ARCH}-${VERSION}
```

then use orderer start
in my case :

```
   DOCKER_NS=hyperledger
    ARCH=x86_64
    VERSION=1.0.0-alpha
```